# Can posterior become tractable if we know p(x)?

Tags: bayesian, inference, autoencoders, variational-bayes, generative-models

In the VAE framework where `x` is an input data (a vector) and `z` is a vector of continuous latent variables,

the posterior `p(z|x)` is intractable because `p(x)` is intractable, so we approximate it using an approximate posterior `q(z|x)`.

But, what happens if we know `p(x)`?

1. e.g., if `p(x) = N(mu, covariance mtx)` is known, does this make the posterior tractable?
2. If yes, does this also apply even if the `covariance mtx` has off-diagonal terms (i.e., elements in the vector `x` are correlated) - or does it not matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bayes theorem is

$$
p(z|x) = \frac{p(x|z)\, p(z)}{p(x)}
$$

so if you know all the components, it's just a multiplication and division. If you don't, you usually need to take the integral

$$
p(x) = \int \, p(x|z)\, p(z) \,dz
$$

and the integral is often intractable. Correlated elements have nothing to do with that.